# Install QChart.js qml module: module not found

Tags: qt, qml

i'm struggling with using a qml module: 
https://github.com/jwintz/qchart.js.

According to [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-identifiedmodules.html#locally-installed-identified-modules)

- I've placed files in $PROJECT/qmlModules/jbQuick/Charts/*.
- Added **QML_IMPORT_PATH** to .pro file.

  QML_IMPORT_PATH += ./qmlModules
- Now I'm trying to import jbQuick.Charts 1.0,

But QtCreator shows error: module not found

[image]

**Update**

After clean build and rerun of qmake, error editor disappeared, but in runtime I'm getting:

> qrc:/analyzer.qml:7 module "jbQuick.Charts" is not installed

**Update**
As mentioned in comments, I've added import paths to main.cpp:

> ```
> engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("qmlModules"));
> ```

But the error still exists.

Disabling the shadow build solves the problem. Looks like I missed something in deploy step (copy of qml module's files)

```
CONFIG += c++11 qml_debug
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick widgets webkit webkitwidgets


HEADERS += VKApi.h \
    VKResponse.h \
    VKRequest.h \
    VKRequestManager.h \
    VKProfileAnalyzer.h \
    VKGroup.h \
    VKDayStats.h

SOURCES += main.cpp \
            VKApi.cpp \
    VKResponse.cpp \
    VKRequest.cpp \
    VKRequestManager.cpp \
    VKProfileAnalyzer.cpp \
    VKGroup.cpp \
    VKDayStats.cpp


RESOURCES += qml.qrc

QML_IMPORT_TRACE = 1

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH += ./qmlModules
QML2_IMPORT_PATH += ./qmlModules

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

Comment: Did you re-run qmake after modifying the .pro file?

Comment: @MrEricSir after clean build and rerunning of qmake, qtcreator doesn't show error anymore in editor, but in runtime I'm getting module "jbQuick.Charts" is not installed

Comment: Would this help: https://github.com/jwintz/qchart.js/issues/3

Comment: @juzzlin yeah, thx. Looks like similar issue, but after adding import paths:
    engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("qmlModules"));
    engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("jbQuick/Charts"));
I'm still getting the error. Disabling the shadow build solves the issue. But looks like I'm missing something with deploy step. Should I add something to deploy the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your comments.

Summarizing all steps required to install QML Module locally (in project dir):

1. Make sure var QML_IMPORT_PATHS is defined in a *.pro

> QML_IMPORT_PATH += ./qmlModules

2. Add import paths in main.cpp (for qmake projects)

> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>     QApplication app(argc, argv);
>
>
>     QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
>     engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("qmlModules"));
>     engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/analyzer.qml")));
>
>     return app.exec();
> }
> ```

3. Make sure plugin's files are correctly deployed. I've used solution from [here](http://dragly.org/2013/11/05/copying-data-files-to-the-build-directory-when-working-with-qmake/)

> ```
> copydata.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $$PWD/qmlModules $$OUT_PWD
> first.depends = $(first) copydata
> export(first.depends)
> export(copydata.commands)
> QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copydata
> ```